# Is there a way to clear/set local notifications from the server?

Tags: cordova, meteor, notifications

I'm using meteor.js and [local notifications](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).  I can use something like

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.cancel([1, 2], function () {
    // Notifications were cancelled
}, scope);
```

to clear local notifications from the mobile device, but if I wanted to do it from another device/computer is there a way? Or would I need to use push notifications?

Comment: You have to reset local notifications from the device, otherwise you need pushnotifications.

Comment: If you are looking to send notifications from server (same or a DDP Connection) and listen on client, I suggest you using gunjansoni:notifications package. https://atmospherejs.com/gunjansoni/notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't use that package, but it should be possible to do something like this:

```
Notifications = new Mongo.Collection("notifications");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var messages = Notifications.find({}).fetch();  // trigger autorun on change to collection
    console.log('cancel notification');
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.cancel([1, 2], function() {
      // Notifications were cancelled
    }, scope);
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    cancelNotification: function() {
      Notifications.insert({message: 'cancel Notification'});
    },

  });
}
```

Meteor.call('cancelNotification') in one client will trigger the autorun in all **connected** clients.  With a bit more code (filtered publication logic) you can target specific client(s), and/or specific notifications.

Comment: This is a cool idea.  So i'm reading about `Tracker.autorun` now, but will it run while the app/s are closed?

Comment: If it's closed the autorun will not trigger.  However this restriction is within the scope of the original question, as you can only clear (or schedule) a Local Notification when the app is running.   You need Push Notifications when the app is not running.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but you're right, it is within the scope of the original question.  Thanks.